# Limit at infinity of a bounded function

Tags: calculus

I was wondering if (1) $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = a$, (2) $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$, (3) $f(x) < a$ for all $x$ and

$$
(4) \; \; 0 \leq x ( a- f(x)) < C
$$
for some positive constant $C$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} x \; f'(x) = 0$.

Btw, the domain of $x$ is the nonnegative real numbers. Thanks,

Comment: I was wondering if you question wasn't in fact an exercise that was given to you, and if so, what you have tried already before posting it here.

Comment: At least this question is plausible...$f(x)=a-e^{-x}$ could fit this profile...

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{If your limit exists then it must be zero, because we have:}$$

$$0\leq x(a-f(x))<C$$
$$\implies 0\leq \frac{a-f(x)}{1/x}<C$$
$$\implies 0\leq\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a-f(x)}{1/x}<C$$

$$\text{ But by L'hospital rule:}$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a-f(x)}{1/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(a-f(x))}{\frac{d}{dx}1/x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-f'(x)}{-1/x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2f'(x)$$

$$\implies 0\leq \lim_{x\to\infty}x^2f'(x)<C$$
$$\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}xf'(x)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment because of my reputation, but I wanted to point out that Ethan's solution is correct and twilight's counterexample is NOT a counterexample because:

1) $\lim_{x\to\infty}xf'(x)$ does not exist and,

2) $f(x) = a$ for $x = \frac{3\pi}{2} + 2\pi k,\ k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. I found a counterexample:

$$
f(x) = a - \frac{1+\sin x}{2+x}
$$

So the fact that $x(a-f(x))$ is bounded above itself is not enough for the conjecture to hold true.

Comment: Note this is only true because $\lim_{x\to\infty}xf'(x)$ does not exist, this is because the cosine function appearing in $f'(x)$ constantly oscillates and prevents the limit from converging to a fixed value. However if his limit does exist, then it will always be zero.